# 'posts_per_page' => '10' does not show any post

Tags: posts, loop

everybody,

I have created a custom_post_type;

```
function create_post_type_veranstaltungen()
{
register_post_type('veranstaltungen', array(
        'label' => __('Veranstaltungen'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-site-alt',
        'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'title', 'editor', 'author', 
        'excerpt', 'comments'),
      )
  );
}
add_action('init', 'create_post_type_veranstaltungen');
```

with its own section of taxonomies

```
function tr_create_my_taxonomy()
{

register_taxonomy(
    'veranstaltungen-category',
    'veranstaltungen',
    array(
        'label' => __('Category'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'veranstaltungen-category'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
    )
);
}

add_action('init', 'tr_create_my_taxonomy');
```

Then I created 4 post and I implemented the corresponding loop that works

```
<?php

            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

            $custom_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'veranstaltungen',
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'paged' => $paged,
                'posts_per_page' => '10'

            );
            $wp_query = new WP_Query($custom_args);

            if (have_posts()) :
                while (have_posts()) : the_post();


             ?>

            <div class="pagination">
                <?php
                    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

                    echo paginate_links(array(
                    base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
                    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                     'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
                     'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
                       ));
                 ?>
            </div>
```

if income posts_per_page => '-1' works, if I enter posts_per_page => '1' also works, but if I enter posts_per_page => '10' does not show anything at all.

Does anyone have an idea of what may be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your last block of code? `archive-veranstaltungen.php`?

Answer (score 0):

after days of research, I found that the fault was simply in the pagination.
By changing the pagination code, I have made it work.

```
<?php

                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

                $custom_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'veranstaltungen',
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'posts_per_page' => '10'
                );
                $wp_query = new WP_Query($custom_args);

                if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

                    ?>

                    <div class="accordion">
                        <div class="columns is-mobile is-flexend ">
                            <div class="column is-half">
                                <div class="columns is-mobile is-vcentered">
                                    <div class="column is-one-fifth">
                                        <i class="angle fa fa-angle-down fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column is-four-fifths">
                                        <?php
                                        $categories = get_the_terms($custom_args->ID, 'veranstaltungen-category');
                                        $cats = ''; // set empty string as  value

                                        foreach ($categories as $i => $category) {
                                            if ($i) echo ', ';
                                            echo '<span>' . $category->name . '</span>';
                                        }
                                        ?>

                                        <div class="title">
                                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="column is-half">
                                <div class="postdate">
                                    <p><?php the_field('tag') ?></p>
                                    <p><?php the_field('datum') ?></p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="thepanel">
                        <div class="theimage">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <div class="columns is-mobile">
                        <div class="column is-3 is-offset-9">
                            <div class="pagination">
                                <?php
                                $nav = get_the_posts_pagination(array(
                                    'mid_size' => 2,
                                    'prev_text' => 'Zurück',
                                    'next_text' => 'Vor',
                                    'screen_reader_text' => 'A'
                                ));
                                $nav = str_replace('<h2 class="screen-reader-text">A</h2>', '', $nav);
                                echo $nav;
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;
                wp_reset_query();
                ?>
```

Ahora funciona perfectamente. Gracias a todos

Answer (score -1):

you have missed $wp_query like this $wp_query->have_posts() to add in the loop. 
Please see the code:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query($custom_args); 
if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
```

Comment: A custom query is not the proper way to change the number of posts per page.

Comment: the result is the same

Comment: Try to change the number of posts by pre_get_posts.

Comment: See the sample code for modifying the number of posts using pre_get_posts.
function posts_per_page_veranstaltungen_cpt( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && ($query->get('post_type') == 'veranstaltungen' )) {
      $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '10' );
    }
  }
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'posts_per_page_veranstaltungen_cpt' );

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code :

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $custom_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'veranstaltungen',
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'paged' => $paged,
                'posts_per_page' => '10'
            );
            $wp_query = new WP_Query($custom_args);

        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
            $wp_query->the_post();

                 echo '<lable>Post Name : ' . get_the_title() .'</lable><br/>';
        }
        wp_reset_query();
           ?>
            <div class="pagination">
                <?php
                    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

                    echo paginate_links(array(
                    'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
                    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                     'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
                     'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
                       ));
                 ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: A custom query is not the proper way to change the number of posts per page.

Comment: but the question is not for change the posts per page number. issue is not showing post when set posts_per_page 10.

Comment: @Dario did you try above code ? i have tested on my machine and it is working. please let me know.

Comment: don't work, i have a custom lopp, maybe that is the problem

Comment: **echo "<pre>";
            print_r( $wp_query);
            echo "</pre>";** after custom query object then find [posts_per_page] object. can you please tell me what do see ?